# Using Bayes Theorem To Simplify Probabilities

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

I want to compute P(AB|X) in terms of the (given) probabilities P(B), P(X), P(A|BX), P(AB, !X), P(A|!B,X), P(A|!B, !X) where every letter is some random variable.

How would I go about doing so using Bayes and other probability rules?

Comment: Given the exclamation marks, I suspect the letters may represent events rather than random variables.

Comment: What i s $!A$? Is it $\overline A$ ?